# Ruby, record a VCR cassette when clicking link in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, capybara, vcr

I have this:

```
@javascript
Given A

Given /$A^/ do
  VCR.use_cassette 'a_cassette' do
     click_link 'a_link' # This makes an AJAX request to external server
  end
end
```

Does not record a cassette, [I can't use tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907347/vcr-badalias-error-when-used-with-cucumber-tag), need this to be done inside step definition.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer instead of posting it in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used sleep and worked for me.

```
Given /$A^/ do
  VCR.use_cassette 'a_cassette' do
     click_link 'a_link' # This makes an AJAX request to external server
     sleep 3
  end
end
```

## Update

```
click_link 'a_link'
page.should have_content 'some content'

# some model assertion
```

With `page` call [Capybara will wait](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara).